# How to implement Stanford's NLP on the web

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, stanford-nlp

I have made a project using Stanford's NLP API and models. I want to implement this Java project on the web. I saw that there is a [demo](http://nlp.stanford.edu:8080/corenlp/) that Stanford-NLP themselves put. So how do they do it? How do they call their java methods and java API in the browser? Do they use AJAX and a back0end Java server? I want to do something like this.

Any help and direction on how to approach the problem is appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: You'll probably get more help if you give it a try first and then come back with a specific question, ideally with code demonstrating your specific problem.

Comment: OK. So I was just reading that using ajax and a servlet would be good enough. Now I do not know what other class I have to create in Java so that it can work with the javascript. Like do I have to make a servlet?

Answer (score 1):

In the next CoreNLP release -- and already on Github (EDIT: this is in CoreNLP as of version 3.6.0) -- we have a `StanfordCoreNLPServer` class:

https://github.com/stanfordnlp/CoreNLP/blob/master/src/edu/stanford/nlp/pipeline/StanfordCoreNLPServer.java

If you run this, you can now make requests to the server with a list of annotators and text to annotate and receive JSON formatted responses. You can see an example in the `corenlp-brat.*` files in:

https://github.com/stanfordnlp/CoreNLP/tree/master/src/edu/stanford/nlp/pipeline/demo.

In particular:

https://github.com/stanfordnlp/CoreNLP/blob/master/src/edu/stanford/nlp/pipeline/demo/corenlp-brat.js#L445.